# Error when downloading PIL/Pillow for Mountain Lion 10.8.5

Tags: python-2.7, pip, easy-install, python-imaging-library

When I tried `sudo pip install PIL` and `sudo easy_install PIL`, they both gave me the following error.

```
unable to execute clang: No such file or directory

error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1
```

I have tried it with `brew install libtiff libjpeg webp littlecms` beforehand, and with `sudo` and without `sudo`, but every time it gives the exact same error.

Comment: What package is `PIP`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Fixed the problem by first installing [Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/) from the App Store, then installing Command Line Tools from the Downloads section of Xcode's Preferences screen.**

Then Try these commands:

```
% brew install pil
% easy_install pip
% pip install pil
```